# IIS caching and web services

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, iis, caching

I am hosting my wcf services with http binding under IIS.

Lately I noticed that there is going on some caching of some sort.

I need to refresh my web service till I am getting the real data, and not that been few minutes ago.

Is there a way to disable this sort of caching ? and how to do so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `[AspNetCacheProfile("NoCacheProfile")]` attribute to the service method(s) that is defined like this in the web.config for the application (child of the `<system.web>` element) :

```
<caching>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="NoCacheProfile" noStore="true" duration="0" varyByParam="none" enabled="true"/>
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

This is a .NET Framework 4 [feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230443.aspx).